# Execution failed for task :app:processDebugGoogleServices

Tags: android

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.2.0.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.nadav.firebasedemo"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'



    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: share your **`Build.Gradle`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Update your **`firebase`** **`dependencies`** because You need to use same version of `dependencies` in your **`build.Gradle`**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are **using 3 different version** of firebase libraries.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
```

**You have to use the same version.**

Use the latest version:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
```